# Regex not working with sed

Tags: regex, sed

i have this text in file

```
"0000000441244"
"0000000127769"
```

I want to replace all zeros with 'L'

I am trying this and nothing gets chnaged

`sed -e 's/0+/L/g' regex.txt`

`sed -e 's/(0+)/L/g' regex.txt`

I want to know where i am wrong

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Posix compliant version should use `00*` instead of `0+`:

```
sed -e 's/00*/L/g' regex.txt
```

As a side note, you only need the `g` flag if you want to convert `"000000012700009"` or even `"000000012709"` into `"L127L9"`. Otherwise, the `*` in `'s/00*/L/'` will include all zeros at the beginning anyway.

Answer (score 7):

In Linux(GNU version's sed), both `sed -e 's/0\+/L/g' regex.txt` and `sed -r 's/0+/L/g' regex.txt` will do,
but if you are using Mac(BSD version's sed), neither of them works, instead you have to use this:
`sed -E 's/0+/L/g' regex.txt`.

Actually the last one works in Linux too, so it's more portable.
For this particular problem, @perreal's suggestion is also portable. But when you do need `+` or other metacharacter in regex, you'd better know how to work around it.

Comment: God bless you, your family, and your regex-fu. I was getting crazy on the BSD version of sed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sed -e 's/0\+/L/g' regex.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any flavor of Unix *except* GNU, you can either install GNU sed yourself or just switch to `awk` or `ruby` or `perl`.

For example:

```
ruby -e 'ARGF.each{|l|puts l.gsub(/0+/, "L")}' regex.txt
```

Using awk:

```
awk '{gsub("0+", "L"); print $0}' regex.txt
```

Extended regular expressions are available on Mac OS/X via `-E` rather than `-e`.

From the "BSD General Commands Manual":

> ```
> -E    Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular 
>       expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).
>       The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.
> ```

Comment: why do people make simple things overly complex

Comment: Haha, don't you hate when that happens?  Just because you know `00*` is exactly the same as `0+` doesn't mean it will pop into your head when you need it.  The `00*` solution is awesome.  So is GNU. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/0/L/' file
```