# Delete word from file using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to delete all words like alias111 or alias123 using regexp alias[0-9]* from some .SQL files. I am using this command:

```
$ sed -e 's/alias[0-9]+/ g/' input.sql > check.txt
```

However, I still have this alias word in my check.txt. I've also tried some other variants of this command, but no mostly no difference.

I have sed (GNU sed) 4.7, Packaged by Debian.

Comment: Use `sed -E 's/alias[0-9]+//g'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex not working with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190068/regex-not-working-with-sed)

Comment: Read about `-E` in your sed man page, then read about the different flavours of [Regular expression syntaxes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes)

Answer (score 0):

As [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) told, the correct command was

```
sed -E 's/alias[0-9]+//g'
```